# What is wrong with my render code?

Tags: 7, chaos-tool-suite

I am trying to create a custom content pane where I would be able to specify 8 values and create 4 divs with 2 values in each one of them. For this I am extending cTools module by creating a plugin. I am already able to fetch input and store it in `$conf` variable. The problem is that it seems that everything I do in render `function` doesn't work. At first I though I had some naming problems. My module name is

> uzduotis

And here is my code for render function:

```
function uzduotis_render($subtype, $conf, $args, $context) {


  $block = new stdClass();
  $block->title = "4Divs";

  $html = '';
  foreach ($conf as $key => $items) {
       $html .= '<div class="element">' . $items['text'] . $items['link'] . '</div>';   
  }

  $block->content=$html;

  return $block;

  dpm($block);
}
```

I try to dpm my block and I get nothing, also another strange thing is that even a block title doesn't show up which I guess notifies that something is completely wrong. Can someone please point out what is wrong? If you need some additional information, please ask for it and I will update. Thank you in advance.

Comment: So are you trying to leverage the Drupal Blocks system, or are you just using the variable $blocks as a personal preference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Blocks need to be render array. You are returning an object. This is how to do it:

```
function uzduotis_render($subtype, $conf, $args, $context) {
  $block = array(
    'title' => '4Divs',
    'content' => array(),
  );

  foreach ($conf as $key => $items) {
    $block['content'][] = array(
      '#prefix' => '<div class="element">',
      '#suffix' => '</div>',
      '#markup' => $items['text'] . $items['link'],
    );
  }

   return $block;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, but I still can't solve this problem. In my $conf variable I have values named like this: text1, link1, text2, link2 ... text4, link4. Every number after variable name is indicating in which div element it will be stored. But on the markup I only have text and link and I am not sure how to add these into it.

Comment: I don't really understand the problem from your question, but it's different from the original question, so you should start a new thread/question on the matter.

Comment: I did what you said and you can find my new topic [Here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/215936/exteing-ctools-and-creating-a-custom-panel-rendering-doesnt-work-at-all)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot run any code after a `return` statement. By definition the `return` will exit the function. Try moving the `dpm` call to just before the `return` statement.

As an aside, I believe that best practices say that $block->content should be a [render array](https://www.drupal.org/node/930760) and not straight up html...